# Apache Rewrite Rules for address bar location

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I'm currently trying to make a rewrite rule which will show http://mywebsite.com/login/ in the address bar, but actually read from http://mywebsite.com/index.php?action=login.  I've tried the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ /?$.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

The URL still shows up as http://mywebsite.com/index.php?action=login, though.

Basically, I want a SEO style links, I guess.

Comment: You want to redirect only "home", "blogs" and "login"?

Comment: I want to redirect 'index', 'blogs', 'projects', 'contact', and 'login' - for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you can use (static version):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(index|blogs|projects|contact|login)/?$ index.php?action=$1 [L,NC]
```

As you can see, each "page" is hard-coded in the rule between the `()`.

You can also make it more "dynamic":

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1 [L,NC]
```

This will automatically use any letters (I added dash and numbers - like index, contact or contact-us) and use it as "action". So in your script you can check if one of these is not accepted (for example someone type: not-a-good-page) then you can redirect to a 404. This way, your script controls the logic not the .htaccess.

Comment: When I try to use `$_GET['page'];` it cannot find it when I try to load http://mysite.com/anything_here/, is there a specific way I have to use it?

Comment: It should be: `$_GET['action']`, if you want to use `page` you can change the rule to: `RewriteRule ^(index|blogs|projects|contact|login)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
`

Comment: I changed them around but it still won't accept my page parameter.

Comment: I changed `/?$.php?page=$1` from your rule to: `index.php?action=$1` and then I get in PHP (when i print_r(_$GET)): `Array ( [page] => login )`  for `http://www.domain.com/login`. Do you have any other rules in your apache config?